# How to get element on which another element drop in ngDraggable AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

We are using ngDraggable in AngularJS , now we want to get the element on which the another element is drop , we get the data of drag element by using ng-drag-data , but we are unable to get data on which the it dropped . It goes in ng-repeat

```
<div class="week" ng-repeat="week in weeks">
    <span class="day" cal-week data-week="{{week.weekNumber}}">
        <label  for="{{week.weekNumber}}">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="day[week.weekNumber]" id="{{week.weekNumber}}" />{{week.weekNumber}}
        </label>
    </span>

    <span class="day {{day.name}} {{week.weekNumber}}"
          cal-date ng-class="{ today: day.isToday, 'different-month': !day.isCurrentMonth}"
          data-date="{{day.getTime | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"
          ng-repeat="day in week.days" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="'{{day.getTime | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}'" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event,ele)" on-dra-end="end()">{{day.number}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, instead, to get the element where we droped the "dragging element", I injected it in the callback evt

// @ ngDrop directive

```
if (attrs.ngDropSuccess) {
    $timeout(function(){
        obj.dropedAtEl = angular.element(element);
        onDropCallback(scope, {$data: obj.data, $event: obj, $target: scope.$eval(scope.value)});
    });
}
```

Now you have it available at the callback through `evt.dropdAtEl`

Answer (score 0):

I do this by make a change in ngDrop directive

```
$timeout(function(){
                 onDropCallback(scope{$data:obj.data,$event:obj,$element:element});//add //$element:element
                      });
```

This is the only way or we have any better approach ?